# What does HDFS provide to HBase?

Tags: hbase

I have read about a lot of features of hbase like persistance,scalablility , fault tolerance , random writes etc. But is there any feature that HDFS provide to hbase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The actual files of HBase is stored in HDFS, thus get replicated to multiple hadoop data nodes automatically. Compare this with Canssandra, another popular column family store, which need to implement its own replication strategy.
- The fact that the data is stored in HDFS provides a good basis for HBase MapReduce integration: Jobs can be easily splitted so that each data node can handle the part of data which is already stored in it, thus reducing the data transfer among the nodes.

References: http://www.larsgeorge.com/2009/10/hbase-architecture-101-storage.html